# NOT NULL constraint failed: user_profile.user_id

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, python-3.6

I'm try to make Sign Up form With Profile Model and I will make some changes in the model.

All tables are created when I run `manage.py makemigrations` but when I want to run manage.py migrate then is show this error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   user_profile.user_id

**Model.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,default="", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

**Views.py**:

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user.refresh_from_db()
        user.profile.birth_date = form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
         user.save()
        user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
else:
    form = SignUpForm()
return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

**form.py**:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
birth_date = forms.DateField(help_text='Required. Format: YYYY-MM-DD')

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'birth_date', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have `default=""` in foreign key as it is not User id, also foreign keys is not set to be NULL-able. This is why foreign key constraint fails.

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, default=None, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: that is not working for me.. And when i delete the database and create the new then it work properly...

Answer (score 0):

You must set the pk value equal to the `user_id` (`user_id=pk`)(here the pk is related to the user model) you can this in View.py