# NOT NULL constraint failed: new__common_farmmodel.user_id

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a part of application for the farmer. I did part with registration, loggin and option "add new farm" for the loggin user, but when I tried to add new farm (filled all fields and click on "POST") it was:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: 
>   new__common_farmmodel.user_id

I found this [NOT NULL constraint failed: user_profile.user_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49296083/not-null-constraint-failed-user-profile-user-id)
    and tried redo my FarmModel, by now when tried migrate I get:

```
      File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
        main()
      File "manage.py", line 17, in main
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
        res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 234, in handle
        fake_initial=fake_initial,
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
        state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
        state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
        state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
        operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 249, in database_forwards
        schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 137, in alter_field
        super().alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, strict=strict)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 535, in alter_field
        old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 359, in _alter_field
        self._remake_table(model, alter_field=(old_field, new_field))
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 286, in _remake_table
        self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 137, in execute
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
        return super().execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
        return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
        return executor(sql, params, many, context)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
        raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\filip\.virtualenvs\ToDoBees\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__common_farmmodel.user_id
```

My actual part of code:

````
    # models.py

    FARMER = 'Farmer'
    BEEKEEPER = 'Beekeeper'
    BUYER = 'Buyer'
    USER_TYPE_WITH_NAME_CHOICES = [(FARMER, 'Farmer'), (BEEKEEPER, 'Beekeeper'), (BUYER, 'Buyer')]


    class CustomUser(BaseUser):
        user = BaseUserManager()
        role = models.CharField(choices=USER_TYPE_WITH_NAME_CHOICES, max_length=10, default=BUYER)
        telephone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
        add_new_farm = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    class FarmModel(models.Model):
        user = ForeignKey(CustomUser, default=CustomUser, null=None, on_delete=CASCADE)
        is_fallen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        it_forest = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        farm_location = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        since_when_sown = models.DateField()
        field_size = models.IntegerField()
        additional_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
        crop_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    # serializers.py

    class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        password = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, min_length=4, required=True, label='Set your password', write_only=True)
        password2 = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, min_length=4, label='Confirm Password', write_only=True)
        telephone = serializers.CharField(max_length=12, label='Enter your phone number', required=False)
        from .models import USER_TYPE_WITH_NAME_CHOICES
        role = serializers.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=USER_TYPE_WITH_NAME_CHOICES)

        class Meta:
            model = CustomUser
            fields = ('email', 'role', 'password', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'telephone')

        def create(self, validator_data):
            user = CustomUser.objects.create()
            user.set_password(validator_data['password'])
            user.save()
            return user

        def hash_password(password):
            salt = hashlib.sha256(os.urandom(60)).hexdigest().encode('ascii')
            pwdhash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', password.encode('utf-8'), salt, 100000)
            pwdhash = binascii.hexlify(pwdhash)
            return (salt + pwdhash).decode('ascii')

        def verify_password(stored_password, provided_password):
            salt = stored_password[:64]
            stored_password = stored_password[64:]
            pwdhash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', provided_password.encode('utf-8'), salt.encode('ascii'), 100000)
            pwdhash = binascii.hexlify(pwdhash).decode('ascii')
            return pwdhash == stored_password

        def validate(self, attrs):
            if attrs.get('password') != attrs.get('password2'):
                raise serializers.ValidationError('Those passwords don\'t match.')
            return attrs


    class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = CustomUser
            fields = ('add_new_farm',)


    class AddFarmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

        class Meta:
            model = FarmModel
            fields = ('is_fallen', 'it_forest', 'farm_location', 'since_when_sown', 'field_size', 'additional_description', 'crop_type')

        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = self.context.get('user')
            validated_data['user'] = user
            return FarmModel.objects.create(**validated_data)

    # views.py

    User = get_user_model()


    class UserRegistration(CreateAPIView):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
        authentication_classes = ()
        permission_classes = ()

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            self.perform_create(serializer)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


    def login_request(request):
        return render(request=request, template_name='')


    class LoggedUserView(ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = UserSerializer

        def list(self, request, **kwargs):
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
            serializer = UserSerializer(queryset)
            return Response(serializer.data)


    class AddFarm(CreateAPIView):
        queryset = FarmModel.objects.all()
        serializer_class = AddFarmSerializer


        def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            data = request.data.copy()
            data['user'] = request.user
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            self.perform_create(serializer)
            user = request.user
            serializer = AddFarmSerializer(AddFarm, context={'user': user})
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should use boolean field for null. `null = None` does not make sense.
You can use
 `null= True` or `null=False`

Here you have to use `null=True`
because you want null value(by default) supported field

Documentation link [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#field-options)

Comment: I set null=False, but still have: `NOT NULL constraint failed:` `new__common_farmmodel.user_id` when try migrate

Comment: you have to use null=True otherwise it will expect some value for the field, for each object(row) created.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that is not problem in model, I think so... Tell me, it is good code in views:

```
class AddFarm(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = FarmModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AddFarmSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data.copy()
        data['user'] = request.user
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        user = request.user
        serializer = AddFarmSerializer(AddFarm, context={'user': user})
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

and in serializers:

```
class AddFarmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    class Meta:
        model = FarmModel
        fields = ('is_fallen', 'it_forest', 'farm_location', 'since_when_sown', 'field_size', 'additional_description',
                  'crop_type')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self._context.get('user')
        validated_data['user'] = user
        return FarmModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

?

I can't find any solution :/