# Integrity Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: users_profile.user_id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to implement update User Profile,in django rest framework.
I am getting the above mentioned error, no matter what I try and change in my code.
Below is the the code for my user serializers, user model and api views.

users/api/serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models import User,Profile



class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','first_name','last_name','phone','id')




class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   

    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user', 'bio', 'image')



    def update(self,instance,validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user',{})
        user = instance.user
        instance.bio = validated_data.get('bio',instance.bio)
        instance.image = validated_data.get('image',instance.image)
        instance.save()
        return instance

Is there anything wrong in my serializer, cause I tried hardcoding and saving a particular user profile also by using for ex: instance.user.id = 21 and then saving it, but i get the same error
```

Is there anything wrong in my serializer, cause I tried hardcoding and saving a particular user profile also by using for ex: instance.user.id = 21 and then saving it, but i get the same error

users/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.conf import settings
import os
import random
import string



class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self,phone,username,first_name,last_name):
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a valid phone number")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a valid username")
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a valid First Name")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a valid last name")


        user = self.model(
            phone=phone,
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name

        )

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,username,phone,first_name,last_name,password = None):
        user = self.create_user(
               username=username,
               phone=phone,
               first_name=first_name,
               last_name=last_name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=20)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date_joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last_login', auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    otp = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='')


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username','first_name','last_name']


    objects = MyAccountManager()



    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self,perm,obj = None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

users/api/views.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import UserSerializer,UserProfileSerializer
from ..models import User,Profile
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class ProfileViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Profile
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['user']
```

Comment: Please remove `id` from your fields.Like this. `id` is automatically saved not  overwrite.
`class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username','first_name','last_name','phone')`

Comment: ok! will do it.

Comment: but removing the id, still doesn't solve the problem, i get the same error.

Comment: someone help me with this plzz....

Comment: This link may helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63546367/not-null-constraint-failed-blog-userpost-user-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add `null=True` if you want to insert null value.This is my suggestion

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

Comment: Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49296083/not-null-constraint-failed-user-profile-user-id

Comment: thanks!  but i dont want user data to be null there, though, yes it solves the error, but i dont want info on user to be nulll.

Comment: Are you need if  user data is exist then update it ,other wise insert newly ??

Comment: no, i just want to update an existinig user profile, withoout touching the user data, only allowing bio and image to be updated