# NOT NULL constraint failed: forum_question.user_id (django)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save an object using cbv's im new to using it, and I'm trying to save an object using create view but is getting this error:

"NOT NULL constraint failed: forum_question.user_id"

I would appreciate beginner friendly explanation on how to fix this and maybe tips as well, thank you!

models.py:

```
class Question(VoteModel, models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    detail = models.TextField()
    tags = models.TextField(default='')
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py:

```
class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['title', 'detail', 'tags']
```

views.py:

```
class AskForm(CreateView):
    def post(self):
        user = self.request.user
        model = Question
        form_class = QuestionForm
        template_name = 'forum/ask-question.html'
        if form_class.is_valid():
            form_class.save()
```

exceptions?:

[image]

edit 3:

[image]

extra info:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 101, in dispatch
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 174, in post
return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 144, in post
return self.form_valid(form)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 127, in form_valid
self.object = form.save()
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 466, in save
self.instance.save()
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vote/models.py", line 67, in save
super(VoteModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 743, in save
self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 780, in save_base
updated = self._save_table(
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 885, in _save_table
results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 923, in _do_insert
return manager._insert(
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1301, in _insert
return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1441, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in **exit**
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/titanium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 416, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: forum_question.user_id
[14/Apr/2022 09:58:02] "POST /ask/ HTTP/1.1" 500 175023

Comment: When you create the `QuestionForm` using the `Question` model you need to add a `User` because you made it a ForeignKey relation AND you haven't specified it to be NULL (required) by default it is required (NOT NULL).

Answer (score 1):

A forum question instance must have a non null user field, but you are not specifying the user related to the object you're creating. In the case you dont want to add the user, update your model's user field to be:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

or in your ask form you overload form_valid() in order to add the user sort of like this (Note I have not tested this directly, follow the [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user)):

```
   class AskForm(CreateView):
       def post(self):
           user = self.request.user
           model = Question
           form_class = QuestionForm
           template_name = 'forum/ask-question.html'
           if form_class.is_valid():
               form_class.save()

        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: it didn't work, the same error comes up :(

Comment: Could you provide the full exception or point to which line is causing the exception, that will help in understanding how to fix the problem.

Comment: hello, do you mean this?

Comment: The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: forum_question.user_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:

Comment: response = await sync_to_async(response_for_exception, thread_sensitive=False)(request, exc)
            return response
        return inner
    else:
        @wraps(get_response)
        def inner(request):
            try:
                response = get_response(request) …
            except Exception as exc:
                response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
            return response
        return inner

Comment: Also I think this is worth mentioning, I'm using a customuser model, thanks again!

Comment: @TitaniumTronic sadly, the error messages do not help as much as i would have thought, but I did find a question that is similar to yours which may help you solve this problem. Heres the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63546367/not-null-constraint-failed-blog-userpost-user-id

Comment: @TitaniumTronic The exceptions you provided say "The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: forum_question.user_id)", and then you provide the rest of the trace, but what is it referring to by "the above exception"? You have to follow the stack trace back up the stack until you get to your own code. When you get to your code, that will likely be the source of the error and is what will tell us what the problem is with exactly

Comment: hey, I edited the question above to include a pic on the traceback

Comment: And if all else fails, try changing that line in the Question class to "user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)" and see if it at least fixes that error. It may not be exactly want you want right now, but the important thing is to make sure nothing else is causing problems on top of the current one

Comment: @TitaniumTronic Is that the full thing? I did see that, but if you look at the location of the files those exceptions were coming from, and their code for that matter, its all the location of the error in Django, not your code.

Comment: yo so uhh I tried the user to foreignkey and unfortuantely still didnt work :(

Comment: I asked around on a few discord servers already and existing stack overflow questions, but cant seem to find the solution

Comment: @TitaniumTronic I do hope you know the primary part of that line to change the user to does not have to do with changing to a foreignkey, the important part was adding the parameters ", blank=True, null=True" after "on_delete=models.CASCADE,"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still useful, however, I ran into the same error. You can fix the error by deleting your migration files and the database.
The error is due to the sending of NULL data(no data) to an already existing field in the database, usually after that field have been modified or deleted.